# PHP & MySQL - Problems with UTF-8 encode

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a form with a input that accept UTF-8 characters:

```
<form method="post" action="faz-personagem.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome">
  </div>
  ...
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

And a script that send the data to a database:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

$conexao = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('pan-tactics');

$nome   = $_POST['nome'];

$nome = utf8_encode($nome);

$sql = "INSERT INTO personagens VALUES";
$sql .= "('$nome')";

$resultado = mysql_query($sql);

echo 'Personagem criado com sucesso.';

mysql_close($conexao);

?>
```

I also have specified in the creation of the database the collation `utf8_unicode_ci` and yet what I get is wrong special characters:

[image: When I send the string "João" to the field "nome" of my database]

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that collation is not the same as charset. You need to set your database and table to be in UTF-8 encoding. This can be done with running this SQL command (only need to be done once).

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Furthermore, you should set the `mysql_*` connection to UTF-8. This code should be placed directly after connecting to your database:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

I see you already set the PHP `header` to UTF-8 as well, so that's good.

Keep in mind that usage of `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and no longer maintained; you should switch to PDO or MySQLi for security reasons.

If neither of these steps helped you, you may need to save the document itself as UTF-8 w/o BOM, this can be done in Notepad++ as Format -> Convert to UFT-8 w/o BOM.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Keep in mind though, that all aspects of your applications and scripts should be set to the same charset, so doing all those things above certainly wouldn't hurt!

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem.

This was my solution:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'secretuser', 'secret', 'mydb');
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8mb4");
```

in your case:

```
$conexao = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
mysqli_set_charset($conexao, "utf8mb4");
```

Maybe this will help someone who comes across this old post.

Answer (score 0):

Set your connection with the database to utf-8:
[mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

U should use mysqli_ functions or PDP rather then mysql_ functions!

Answer (score 0):

Check your collation of your database (including columns and tables).
Also, try adding `mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");` after the connection to database in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Were you expecting `João` for the first name?  If so, you have "Mojibake".

`JoÃƒÂ£o` is even worse -- It looks like you Mojibaked `João` to get `JoÃ£o`, then Mojibaked that to get `JoÃƒÂ£o`.